# String replacement on a whole text file in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace

How can I replace a string with another string, within a given text file.  Do I just loop through readline() and run the replacement while saving out to a new file?  Or is there a better way?

I'm thinking that I *could* read the whole thing into memory, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to loop through lines? It's probably the best solution.

Comment: I don't know... I was just wondering if there was a better way I guess.  Rather than creating a new file and removing the old one.

Comment: by creating the new file you remove the need to have the whole file in memory... and if you are doing a re.sub you should make sure you use re.compile first (and then use the returned instance's sub method)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[fileinput](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/fileinput.html?highlight=fileinput#module-fileinput) is the module from the Python standard library that supports "what looks like in-place updating of text files" as well as various other related tasks.

```
for line in fileinput.input(['thefile.txt'], inplace=True):
    print(line.replace('old stuff', 'shiny new stuff'), end='')
```

This code is *all* you need for the specific task you mentioned -- it deals with all of the issues (writing to a different file, removing the old one when done and replacing it with the new one).  You can also add a further parameter such as `backup='.bk'` to automatically preserve the old file as (in this case) `thefile.txt.bk`, as well as process multiple files, take the filenames to process from the commandline, etc, etc -- do read the docs, they're quite good (and so is the module I'm suggesting!-).

Comment: Avoid using "print" and use "sys.stdout.write" instead if you don't wan't "print" to add blank line and CTRL-M after every line

Comment: @Badisi You can accomplish that by setting `print`'s parameter `end`, which by default is set to `\n`, to an empty string. I.e: `print(line, end='')`. See https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print

Answer (score 4):

If the file can be read into memory at once, I'd say that

```
old = myfile.read()
new = old.replace("find this", "replace by this")
output.write(new)
```

is at least as readable as

```
for line in myfile:
   output.write(line.replace("find this", "replace by this"))
```

and it might be a little faster, but in the end it probably doesn't really matter.